# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space-How to resolve this error?

Tags: java, jsp, lucene, tomcat7, heap-memory

I am developing a website in JSP(JDK 1.6) and hosting it using apache tomcat7. There is a webpage which takes user input,builds a query and sends it to Lucene Database(20GB in size) and displays the result in a downloadable textfile.However this functionality is not working properly and I get the following exception after I submit the user Input.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    org.apache.jsp.Getinfo_jsp._jspService(Getinfo_jsp.java:305)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42.Lucene42DocValuesProducer.loadNumeric(Lucene42DocValuesProducer.java:180)
    org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42.Lucene42DocValuesProducer.getNumeric(Lucene42DocValuesProducer.java:146)
    org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.getNormValues(SegmentCoreReaders.java:301)
    org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.getNormValues(SegmentReader.java:259)
    org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.TFIDFSimilarity.exactSimScorer(TFIDFSimilarity.java:760)
    org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:285)
    org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:323)
    org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:323)
    org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:603)
    org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:482)
    org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:438)
    org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
    org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
    com.cde.sentiment.DataCollection.GetTweets(DataCollection.java:76)
    com.cde.sentiment.SentimentCalculation.GenerateOutputFile(SentimentCalculation.java:102)
    org.apache.jsp.Getinfo_jsp._jspService(Getinfo_jsp.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

Here's the stacktrace of above exception

```
24 Jun, 2013 3:04:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SentimentAnalysisModule] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42.Lucene42DocValuesProducer.loadNumeric(Lucene42DocValuesProducer.java:180)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42.Lucene42DocValuesProducer.getNumeric(Lucene42DocValuesProducer.java:146)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.getNormValues(SegmentCoreReaders.java:301)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.getNormValues(SegmentReader.java:259)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.TFIDFSimilarity.exactSimScorer(TFIDFSimilarity.java:760)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:285)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:323)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:323)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:603)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:482)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:438)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
        at com.cde.sentiment.DataCollection.GetTweets(DataCollection.java:76)
        at com.cde.sentiment.SentimentCalculation.GenerateOutputFile(SentimentCalculation.java:102)
        at org.apache.jsp.Getinfo_jsp._jspService(Getinfo_jsp.java:154)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
```

Comment: That will be closed as a duplicate, certainly... Anyway: try and lookup the `-Xmx` option; that is what increases the JVM heap size. By default, it is 64MB.

Comment: You need to know how memory is being consumed. Download Visual VM, install all the plugins, and attach it to the PID when you run Tomcat.  It'll show you what's happening and help you figure out why.

Comment: If you aren't already I suggest running your application on a 64bit JVM as you can assign it more (essentailly unlimited) memory then. A 32bit JVM is limited to about 1200M.

Comment: I am new to Apache Tomcat. I don't understand whether the error is because of my code or some lucene ot tomcat7 problem. Also, my JVM is 32 bit.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki possibly it's not caused by your code, see my response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code with Lucene consumes more memory than declared for the heap. It may not be an error (leak) but only a configuration issue (not enough memory).

1. Try using `-Xmx` to increase the heap size. For Apache Tomcat use i.e. `export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M"`
2. Find how memory is used using some profiling tool i.e. `VisualVM` which is bundled with Oracle JDK.